# How would you use scrapy to select an option from a select tag on a site?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning how to use Scrapy. I was following the tutorial for simulating user login with scrapy and then collecting data after successfully being logged in (code below). However, how would one program scrapy to select a certain option from a drop down list if it was part of the login process?

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

Select tag:

```
<select>

    <option>Value 1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>

</select>
```

How would I program scrapy to select, say Value 1, in a drop down list, in addition to entering the login information.

Comment: There is nothing magical in scrapy about it. Open browser developer tools, network tab, submit the request and see how the dropdown value is presented in the request. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to pass the option & its value as a key in form data like {Value,1}, {Value,2}.

Comment: Would it be something like this: formdata = {'name_of_select_tag': 'optionvalue'} Also, just confirming that the key is always the name attribute in html code.